# Formula checkbox does not check when user views record

Tags: formula-field, checkbox

I created a checkbox formula that checks when ownerid=managerid. As an admin, the checkbox formula field works and updates but when I log in as different user (manager profile) the checkbox is unchecked.
This is the formula I used in the formula I used: OwnerId = $User.ManagerId
Please help. Thank you!
[image: Here is the view from both]

Comment: $User.ManagerId looks at the current user's manager. So it makes sense that it behaves differently when being looked at by a different user. What is the use case you are trying to fulfill?

Comment: The requirement is that Employee's record (client wants to use contact object) should somehow (without manual input) update and show that the employee is a manager. First, I created a flow to create a record under Contacts each time an employee is created and Contact's employee lookup to user field = contact owner, 2nd- I created a formula checkbox field so if the ownerid matches a manager id, then the check box for that field is checked.....now that I'm writing this out, I'm not sure it made sense. A little guidance would be greatly appreciated. @GuyClairbois

Comment: Can you do this by assigning a custom permission to users (via perm set or, less good, profile) who are managers? Or does this need to be more dynamic based on being referenced by a Contact as that Contact's manager? If so you need to add record triggered logic to handle this (e.g. in a trigger) to keep count of the "subordinates".

Comment: So the key question is: how do you know/derive that someone is a manager? If that is defined by 'anyone having them as 'Manager on their user record' then indeed, as Phil says, some record triggered logic (in a trigger or in a flow) is needed to handle all scenarios. But you might have a different definition?